# Collection was modified C# exception but can't figure out why

Tags: c#, .net

I have this piece of code in C#:

```
Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
if(visitedUrls.Contains(url) || visitedUrls.Where( x => x.Contains(root) ).Count() > 150) {
   return;
}
else{
   visitedUrls.Add(url);
}
Thread.EndCriticalRegion();
```

which it's into a function that gets called by several different processes, and that's why I (tried to) make it thread-safe.

The exception `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` raises on the `if` line, but if I leave it as

```
if(visitedUrls.Contains(url)
```

it works fine, why?

**EDIT**
This the actual code:

```
public void scrapAzienda(String url, String root_url, int depth)
{
    if (depth <= 0) return;

    var web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlNode[] nodes = null; 
    HtmlDocument doc = null; 
    HtmlNode bodyNode = null;

    Thread.BeginCriticalRegion();
        if (urlVisitati.Contains(url) || urlVisitati.Where(x => x.Contains(root_url)).Count() > 150)
            return;
        else
            urlVisitati.Add(url);
    Thread.EndCriticalRegion();

    try
    {
        doc = web.Load(url, Proxy.getUrl(), Proxy.getPort(), Proxy.getUsername(), Proxy.getPassword());

        nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]").ToArray() ?? null;

        foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => scrapAzienda(item.Attributes["href"].Value, root_url, depth - 1), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        }

        GC.Collect();

        if (doc != null)
        {
            bodyNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

            cercaNumeri(bodyNode.InnerText, url);
            cercaEmail(bodyNode.InnerText, url);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) {  }
}
```

Basically it's just a webscraper.

Comment: comment: visitedUrls is a global List<string> variable

Comment: Is this inside a loop?  Why are you using `Thread.BeginCriticalSection()`?  This does not look like a critical section of code.

Comment: hi @Amy, that function I mentioned is recursive and that List is shared among different processes which read and write (Add) on it, so I think it should be a critical region, shouldn't it?

Comment: Critical regions only mean "if an exception is thrown here, it won't just take down this thread, it will take down other threads with it".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.begincriticalregion?view=net-5.0  If your intent was to make this code thread-safe, critical sections are not the way to go.  Please expand your code to include this "recursive" calls.

Comment: We need more of your code, enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Amy, I added the entire code, thank you. Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: @Amy: I think you've diagnosed correctly, but saying "critical sections are not the way to go" in your comment is unfortunately contributing to the confusion.  A critical section, like a mutex, *does* help with thread safety.  `BeginCriticalRegion` has nothing to do with critical sections.  **Critical section** and **critical region** are totally different things.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, thank you for pointing that out.  I didn't realize I slipped terms.

Comment: Have you considered a thread-safe collection? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=net-5.0

Comment: Use `ConcurrentBag`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think threading is the entirety of your issue.  `Thread.BeginCriticalRegion()` doesn't do what you think it does.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.begincriticalregion?view=net-5.0):

> Notifies a host that execution is about to enter a region of code in which the effects of a thread abort or unhandled exception might jeopardize other tasks in the application domain.

In other words, it doesn't enforce thread-safety, it just says "if this breaks, it's gonna take everything down with it!"

What you need instead is a basic `lock`:

```
lock(someObj)
{
    if (urlVisitati.Contains(url) || urlVisitati.Where(x => x.Contains(root_url)).Count() > 150)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        urlVisitati.Add(url);
    }
}
```

`someObj` needs to be a static object.  Every thread needs to refer to the same object. I usually create a basic object for this purpose, at the class level:

```
private static readonly object SyncLock = new object();
```

You then use lock with that object: `lock(SyncLock)`.  You can also lock on the list itself, **however**, only one thread can get a lock on the sync object at a time.  To help prevent deadlocks, *your* code should ideally be the only source of locks on whatever object you're syncing on. Can you guarantee something inside the list class itself won't get a lock on itself?  Don't worry about it, make your own sync object.  No big deal.

This is a crash-course into threading with `lock`.  There are other ways of doing this.  This one should work for you.